# Is it possible to detect the presence of an USB expansion card in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, usb, sd-card

I would like to write some C++ program that can detect the presence of an USB expansion card, or an SD card reader without it necessarily having anything plugged in to it. Is this possible? In Linux?

Comment: You might be interested by `lsusb` and `udev` programs. I don't know exactly what system calls they are actually doing. You could use `strace` to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you know the exact vendor id and/or product id you could search for it, like this:

```
for (bus = busses; bus; bus = bus->next)
for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next)
  if ((dev->descriptor.idVendor == vendor) && (dev->descriptor.idProduct == product))
    return dev;
```

[libusb tutorial](http://www.jespersaur.com/drupal/node/25)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can get the idVendor and idProduct by a simple `dmesg`. And then, put a search condition for it just shown above by a knowledgeble man. If you want to dig deeper, and if you have a linux, then you can explore `usb.h` present in your `<kernel_source>/drivers/usb/core`.
There is a structure : `struct usb_device{}`.
If you yet more keen to explore then, you should check out `driver.c` and `hub.c` for methods like `announce_device()` which prints the USB device details after a `dmesg`. Explore it for good! :)